# Constraint Layout with percentage not working as expected

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I would make a view that has 70% width and align to the right of its parent using constraint layout as follow

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.3"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Hello text"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The TextView always occupy full parent width. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two minor but important changes:

1. TextView width should be 0dp i.e. match constraint and not match parent
2. Guideline orientation should be vertical not horizontal

Here's the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.3" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello text"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Output:

[image]

Also note that I changed the ConstraintLayout height to match_parent so that the guideline was visible in the output. You can change it back to wrap_content.