# How to specify in XML a percentage of width and height for a view?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-layout-weight, android-layoutparams

It is possible to add a ImageView inside a XML LinearLayout with the 15% of the width of the screen of width and also exactly the same height?

I tried it with this dialog code which is being displayed when a user clicks on a marker on the map:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_info_bubble"
    android:orientation="vertical">
.
. [some more content here]
.
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/favorite"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="15"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

But is has two problems:

**Problem 1:** android:layout_weight="15" makes 15% of the width of the dialog, not of the screen, and that's a huge problem, because the dialog has some times more or less width depending of its content.

**Problem 2:** the width is 15% ok but the height is the real height of the image. I don't know how to make it to have exactly the same height than it's width. Its a square image, so I tried make it respecting its proportions putting wrap_content on height and adjustViewBounds=true but it didn't work.

**Problem 3:** the ImageView is not being centered, is aligned to the left. I need it centered.

How can this be achieved with XML instead of Java code?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html

Comment: **FYI** @VishvaDave `PercentRelativeLayout`  is deprecated in API level 26.1.0.

Comment: @NileshRathod only in that use if target version is lower

Comment: @NileshRathod Do you have any other option for this? post an answer

Comment: @VishvaDave go with **[ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html)**

Comment: @NileshRathod please can you post an example of how to achieve this with COnstraintLayout? i readed the documentation and didn't find the way to achieve it

Comment: @NullPointerException this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37318228/how-to-make-constraintlayout-work-with-percentage-values  and this also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42958168/constraint-layout-with-percentage-not-working-as-expected

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37318228/how-to-make-constraintlayout-work-with-percentage-values

Comment: @Redman it's impossible for me to understand how to achieve it please can you pust a sample code?

Comment: this https://stackoverflow.com/a/19449488/6478047 and this https://stackoverflow.com/a/46295558/6478047 together should do the trick for you

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do in XML, by this way my image **height** is equal to 15% of the screen **width** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/favorite"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H, 100:15"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Look at the result :

[image: Result]

Comment: Nice approach that doesn't use Guidelines

Comment: Be aware of that works only for square images. ImageView itself take all the screen width.

Answer (score 0):

No, AFAIK it's not possible via XML. 
But you can easy achieve it programmatically:
if you want you can just create a custom view with the required parameters and just put it into XML.
Look into https://stackoverflow.com/a/20427215/1159507 for reference.

Comment: Of course, it is possible via XML ! just watch here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/37369672/5154891

Comment: @ThomasMary if I set percent value in `ConstraintLayout` it will be percent from parent layout, not percent of screen, is not it?

Comment: @ThomasMary I'm checking that post but can't find how to set width and height please can you post an asnwer with your proposed solution?

Answer (score 0):

How to make it take up 15% of the screen width:

```
//Get 15% of screen width:
myWidth = getWindow().getDecorView().getWidth() * .15;

myImageView = findViewById(R.id.favorite);

myView.setWidth(myWidth);

//Height should be the same as the width
myView.setHeight(myWidth);
```

Comment: i was asking by XML not by java

Comment: i will consider your answer if no one solves this with xml

Answer (score 0):

The following two lines say that the width of the image view will be determined in percents and it'll be relative to the parent.

```
app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.15"
```

The following line means that the width and height of the imageview will be the same. The ratio is width:height.

```
app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
```

With `Guidelines` you get the ability to set % widths/heights in views under constraint layout. The following says that the guideline is 20% of its parent. You can then place views with constraint set to this Guidelines.

```
app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.2"
```

Below is a full example xml you can try out.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#423dfe"

        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.15"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"

        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

You can only do this with the beta version of ConstraintLayout:

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta1'
```

Related SO posts:  [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47071262/constraintlayout-relative-distance-in-percentage) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37318228/how-to-make-constraintlayout-work-with-percentage-values) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798392/imageview-have-height-match-width)

Further reading: [Constraint Layout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html)