# constraint layout with percentage Guideline dont work in wrap_content

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

hi guys i want a imageview with the height of 30% of the screen how should i do it? this is my code but its not working when i change the constraintLayout height to match parent it takes all the screen and when i set it to wrap_content now i have nothing in screen
this is my Code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/pic" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.25"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

i want to use it on recyclerview when i set the height to match parent this is how become [image] its a lot of empty space below

**[image: UPDATE]**

Comment: check [Constraint Layout with percentage not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42958168/constraint-layout-with-percentage-not-working-as-expected)

Comment: @Osairon its not working i try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the XML you presented is for each of the items in your `RecyclerView` and that you want each item to take up 1/3 of the height of the `RecyclerView`. A `RecyclerView` item is created in `onCreateViewHolder()` of the adapter and usually just takes into account its own content and inflates to the size it needs to be to hold its content.

You want to impose an external requirement that the `RecyclerView` item must take up 1/3 of the height of the `RecyclerView`. There is no way to do this in XML, so you will have to resort to code.

I thought that this would be easy, but it is a little involved, but bear with me.

You will need to determine the height of the `RecyclerView` so you can compute 1/3 of that value as the height of each item. Unfortunately, as I have discovered, the height of the `RecyclerView` is not determined until the view holders are created. So, we are in a quandary: We need the height of the `RecyclerView` to build the view holders, but the view holders must be built to determine the height of the `RecyclerView`.

To get around this, we will set the height of the `RecyclerView` to `match_parent`. This will make the `RecyclerView` as tall as its parent. We can get the height if the parent before the `RecyclerView` is fully measured. We will employ a global layout listener to capture the height of the parent. This code should be executed after the `RecyclerView` (here `mRecyclerView`) is created and before the adapter is set. In my test suite, I have it defined ion `onCreate()` of the activity.

```
    mRecyclerView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            // Remove the listener so we don't get called again.
            mRecyclerView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            // Capture the height of the parent view group.
            int height = ((ViewGroup) mRecyclerView.getParent()).getHeight();
            // And let the adapter know the height.
            adapter.setItemHeight(height);
            // Now that we know the height of the RecyclerView and its items, we
            // can set the adapter so the items can be created with the proper height.
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    });
```

Add `setItemHeight()` to the adapter to capture the item height.

```
private int mItemHeight;

public void setItemHeight(int parentHeight) {
    mItemHeight = parentHeight / 3;
}
```

Finally, we can use the item height to create the items:

```
@Override
public ItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    view.getLayoutParams().height = mItemHeight;
    return new ItemHolder(view);
}
```

You may need to adjust the item's height if the `RecyclerView` has padding, margins or decorations.

Comment: hi can you please check my answer again in 2 mins?

Comment: i want all of my items in recyclerView takes 30% of the screen @Cheticamp

Comment: @razaAmini Still not clear. I don't see a `RecyclerView` in the XML you presented. What is that XML? Is it the XML for items in the `RecyclerView` or something else? Are you trying to fit exactly three items on-screen in your `RecyclerView`?

Comment: thanks a lot for helping me i need exactly 30% of the screen  for the height of  my view and yes this image view is my recyclerview child my recyclerview is a simple match_parent height and wight recyclerview in a layout

Comment: hi can you please watch my update image please see im trying to build a view like this:recyclerview -> first %30 is a imageview and rest of the items are recyclerview too but with a horizental linearlayoutmanager i really need help thanks a lot i need a layout or view that takes 30% of the screen